# How to use autowire(...), create(...), and get(...) in definitions for PHP-DI?

Tags: dependency-injection, dependencies, php-di

[PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/) 6 provides multiple functions, that working in the [definitions](http://php-di.org/doc/php-definitions.html). Three of them seem to do the same in the definitions context: `autowire(...)`, `create(...)`, and `get(...)`. E.g. I have following types:

```
FooServiceInterface
BarServiceInterface
FooAService implements FooServiceInterface
    dependencies: BarServiceInterface $barService
FooBService implements FooServiceInterface
    dependencies: BarServiceInterface $barService
BarService implements BarServiceInterface
    dependencies: -
```

The `FooServiceInterface` gets injected into a Symfony controller (constructor injection).

Now my file with the definitions:

```
return [
    FooServiceInterface::class => DI\autowire(FooBService::class),
    BarServiceInterface::class => DI\autowire(BarService::class),
];
```

It works.

I also can set it up like this:

```
return [
    FooServiceInterface::class => DI\get(FooBService::class),
    BarServiceInterface::class => DI\get(BarService::class),
];
```

And it's still working.

This

```
return [
    FooServiceInterface::class => DI\create(FooBService::class),
    BarServiceInterface::class => DI\create(BarService::class),
];
```

doesn't work.

And this

```
return [
    FooServiceInterface::class => DI\get(FooBService::class),
    BarServiceInterface::class => DI\create(BarService::class),
];
```

does.

**What is the difference between the three functions (in the context of definitions)? Which one is the recommended function to set up a common interface dependency definition (like `SomeInterface::class => DI\recommendedFunction(SomeClass::class)`)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say use `get()` only if you know why you would need it.

Then to choose between `autowire()` and `create()` is up to you: do you need autowiring or not?

Using simply `create()` is telling PHP-DI to just do `new FooService()` to create the service. If that's enough, then fine. If your service has dependencies, you can either rely on autowiring (using `autowire()`) or define the dependencies to inject manually using `create()`. It's up to you.

Comment: How autowiring impact performance? Taking convenience aside (which makes autowiring a better choice), is there any benefit in using PHP definitions vs autowiring, especially from a performance perspective?

Comment: Found a relevant response here - https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI/issues/731

Comment: For performances, read the documentation: https://php-di.org/doc/performances.html
Don't read issues, they can be outdated.