# How to define all classes in PHP DI definitions.php?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-di

This is my **definitions.php**:

```
return [

  'Entity' => create(Entity::class),
  'Request' => create(Request::class)

]:
```

There can be many classes in a PHP project, do I have to manually register all the classes in the PHP DI container or there's a better way to do it automatically.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474983/how-to-use-autowire-create-and-get-in-definitions-for-php-di